# How to inject http endpoint adresses as a environment in WSO2?

Tags: wso2, wso2-integration-studio

I am calling an http endpoint in WsO2 Integration Studio. How can I give the address of this endpoint externally as envrionment? .Because the addresses of my endpoints are different in dev environment and live environment. I looked at the document about it. But I couldn't do it.
I want to changeable **localhost:XXX** address as a environment

Below is my WSO2 code:

```
         <call>
            <endpoint>
                <http method="get" uri-template="http://localhost:XXX/test">
                    <suspendOnFailure>
                        <initialDuration>-1</initialDuration>
                        <progressionFactor>-1</progressionFactor>
                        <maximumDuration>0</maximumDuration>
                    </suspendOnFailure>
                    <markForSuspension>
                        <retriesBeforeSuspension>0</retriesBeforeSuspension>
                    </markForSuspension>
                </http>
            </endpoint>
        </call>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$SYSTEM:EP_ADDR` as the `uri-template` and set the environment variable `EP_ADDR` on your environment,

```xml
<call>
    <endpoint>
        <http method="get" uri-template="$SYSTEM:EP_ADDR">
            <suspendOnFailure>
                <initialDuration>-1</initialDuration>
                <progressionFactor>-1</progressionFactor>
                <maximumDuration>0</maximumDuration>
            </suspendOnFailure>
            <markForSuspension>
                <retriesBeforeSuspension>0</retriesBeforeSuspension>
            </markForSuspension>
        </http>
    </endpoint>
</call>
```

The above config works in fine MI 4.1.0. If this doesn't help please specify the version you are using.

For more info: https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/micro-integrator/develop/injecting-parameters/#endpoint-parameters

To see how we can inject variables in embed runtime of Integration Studio check https://medium.com/think-integration/how-to-inject-environment-variables-to-wso2-integration-studio-runtime-83b8f0cb882e

Answer (score 1):

What Sanoj mentioned is one option. Another option is to use the `Property Mediator`. This will allow you are dynamically constructing the URL using the Environment variable or file parameters.

```xml
<property expression="concat('https://', get-property('env', 'host'), ':', get-property('env', 'port'))" name="uri.var.ep" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
```

Then use it in your Endpoint configuration

```xml
<call>
   <endpoint>
       <http method="get" uri-template="{uri.var.ep}">
           <suspendOnFailure>
               <initialDuration>-1</initialDuration>
               <progressionFactor>-1</progressionFactor>
               <maximumDuration>0</maximumDuration>
           </suspendOnFailure>
           <markForSuspension>
               <retriesBeforeSuspension>0</retriesBeforeSuspension>
           </markForSuspension>
       </http>
   </endpoint>
</call>
```

**Update**

In order to add them to your runtime you need to export them as environment variables in the server runtime. If you are on a linux environment you can add them into the `integrator.sh` (Depending on the Product you are using this may change.) For example for the given example above you can add the following two lines.

```
export host=abcd.efg.com
export port=8987
```

Comment: How can I export the values in the property in the example? Because I will use the car file I created in wso2 intregration studio in ci cd deployment processes, I need to use this method.

Comment: @AhmetKalem check the update on the answer.